# Rails Polymorphic Association - Two Tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Good afternoon. I'm new to Rails and I'm using google translate to post here.

It has a polymorphic association:
Enter 3 tables with following relationships:

Model: Favorite

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :ata_public
has_many :ata_object
belongs_to :favoriteable, polymorphic: true

validates :user, uniqueness: {scope: [:favoriteable_type, :favoriteable_id]}
```

Model: AtaPublic

```
has_many :ata_objects
has_many :ride_requests
has_many :favorites, as: :favoriteable
belongs_to :provider, class_name: "User"
```

Model: AtaObject

```
belongs_to :ata_public
belongs_to :product
has_many :favorites, as: :favoriteable
```

Table: Favorites
https://i.stack.imgur.com/twWUI.png

How is my Controller create to perform this registration, getting the current user (current_user)?

It currently looks like this:

```
  def create
    @favorite = Favorite.new(favorite_params.merge(user: @current_user))

    if @favorite.save
      render json: @favorite, status: 200
    else
      render json: {error: "Unable to create a bookmark"}, status: 422
    end
  end

  def favorite_params
    params.require(:favorite).permit(:favoriteable_type, :favoriteable_id)
  end
```

The question is, what should my CREATE controller look like?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to create nested routes like this in `routes.rb`

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :ata_publics, :ata_objects do
   resources :favorites, only: :create #-> url.com/ata_objects/:ata_object_id/favorites
end
```

Then your favorite controller is something like this

```
# app/controllers/favorites_controller.rb
class FavoritesController < ApplicationController
   def create
      @parent  = parent
      @favorite = @parent.favorites.new favorite_params
      
      if @favorite.save
       render json: @favorite, status: 200
      else
       render json: {error: "Unable to create a bookmark"}, status: 422
      end
   end

   private

   def parent
      return AtaPublic.find_by_id params[:ata_public_id] if params[:ata_public_id]
      AtaObject.find_by_id params[:ata_object_id] if params[:photo_id]
   end

   def favorite_params
      params.require(:favorite).permit(:your_favorite_attributes).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
   end
end
```